# Ruby (or Rails) type-safe "try"-equivalent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, type-safety

I want to check values in a user-input hash (parameters passed to a Rails controller). I want to protect myself against bogus user input. Object#try protects me against missing input, but what about malformed input?

The simple, unsafe case:

```
  if params[:credentials][:login] …
```

Obviously, if the user hasn't provided the :credentials value, then my attempt to get :login will fail … Nil doesn't have the method :[]. A very nice solution to this is Object#try:

```
  if params[:credentials].try(:[], :login) …
```

But what if the issue is that the user provided malformed credentials? In particular, one of my users passed an array, rather than a hash. So I still get an exception,

```
TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

Is there something rather like try(), that turns any bogosity into false/nil?

The closest I could come is

```
  if begin params[:credentials][:login]; rescue; false; end …
```

Which is a bit cluttered -- though, I grant, still more compact and yet more general than explicit paranoia:

```
  if (params.has_key? :credentials and params[:credentials].is_a? Hash and params[:credentials].has_key? :login) …
```

Comment: Can you give an example of bogus input? If you are trying to protect your models from bad input, be sure to check validations and attr_accessible attributes.

Comment: It's the controller, not the model, where we find ourselves. It's an API … a Rails app without the HTML ;-)

Comment: Expected input: { :credentials => {:login => 'byname', :password => 'whatever'}}

Comment: Actual input that got me started on this: {:credentials => [{:login => 'byname', :password => 'whatever'}]}

Comment: What I meant was, if you are simply passing `params[:credentials]` into a model then there are better ways or validating the contents. For instance, if you wanted to look up a user then you could just do `@user = User.where(params[:credentials]) rescue nil`. Are you using an authentication framework, or are you rolling your own?

Comment: The issue here is not how to validate the  offered credentials, but how to discern if credentials were offered at all. The API defines them as optional (if not provided, then the session provides them). But the API still has to deal with malformed input, since this is a primary entry point (actually, a before_filter to most "real" actions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `begin/rescue` statements here, it costs in performance and your intentions aren't clear. Same with `try` which is simply a `rescue nil` in disguise.

You have to check everything and you check it right. It's just kind of ugly to mix data check and logic.

Since I watched Avdi's Confident Ruby, I changed my way of coding; I suggest you do something like (I just simplified your code a little bit):

```
def your_action
  checked_params_for_action do
    #safe params here
    #your_controller_code
  end
end

private

def checked_params_for_action(&block)
  if (params[:credentials].is_a?(Hash) && params[:credentials][:login])
    yield
  else
    redirect_to root_path, error: "params malformed"
  end
end
```

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto: glad it helped, look here for more: http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/06/05/confident-ruby-beta/

Comment: +1, I do similar things and I think this block/yield structure is sadly under used.

Comment: Interesting video, I'll take some time to watch it. Thanks @apneadiving !

Comment: I must say, I'm really liking that separation-of-concerns block form! Still pondering that "answered" check mark.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought try has the performance cost you imply it has - there's no rescuing going on there.

Comment: @FrederickCheung: right, try has almost no performance cost, I did some benchmark on it. But it acts like a rescue nil. It's very useful bit should be used with parcimony. I can't see it's added value here for instance